# How do I merge these 2 datasets on Jupyter using SQLAlchemy?

Tags: sql, jupyter

I'm currently using the WRDS cloud to connect to their servers so that I can manipulate my data before I download it, so I can run some ML algorithms on it. One way of extracting the data is by using the raw_sql() function that they have built in, presumably from SQLalchemy. The reason I'm trying to merge both of these is because I need 2 columns that aren't available in the first data set. I'm trying to merge them based on the security ID and the date, but I keep getting an empty table.

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
company = conn.raw_sql("""select a.symbol, a.strike_price, a.optionid, a.impl_volatility, a.open_interest, a.volume, 
                      a.vega, a.best_bid, a.best_offer, a.date, a.exdate, b.underlyingbid, b.underlyingask 
                      
                      
                      from optionm.opprcd2020 a
                      inner join optionm.option_price_2020 b
                      
                      on a.optionid = b.optionid
                      and a.date = b.date
                      
                      
                      where a.volume > 500
                      and a.volume > 0.5 * a.open_interest
                      and a.cp_flag = 'C' 
                      and (a.exdate - a.date) <= 30 and (a.exdate-a.date) > 0 
                      and a.best_bid > 0.3   
                      LIMIT 50""") # use raw_sql() method to open 2020 options data with relevant info
```

The relevant documentation is here: https://www.fredasongdrechsler.com/intro-to-python-for-fnce/maneuvering-wrds-data

Comment: All relevant information should be in the question, not off-site. And aliases like `a` and `b` don't help readability. What do you mean by "I'm trying to merge"?

Comment: My apologies, will edit it to try and include your advice. What I mean by 'merging' is im trying to join these 2 data sets together.